# Is whey good for dogs?

Tags: dogs, diet

Is it safe to give a puppy liquid whey left over from cheese making? I read somewhere that it is fine and I am curious if that's true as it sounds a bit crazy for that to be true to me.

Comment: I have a gut feeling that this would mess with the dog's balanced diet.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, whey [contains 6% lactose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whey#Health)  we know from the answers to the question [Is it OK to feed dogs dairy products?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5442) that giving dairy products to adult dogs is problematic.  We also know from the question [If my pet is lactose intolerant does that mean they can't have any dairy products?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7363) that lactose can lead to flatulence, diarrhea, nausea.

Many commercial dog food products include protein from whey, but that is a processed product (presumably with the lactose removed).

A puppy who should not have developed lactose intolerance, and should be able to digest **MODERATE** amounts of whey just like they would a complete milk product (see related: [Question about getting a mother's milk from another species](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10696))

Watch for loose stool and/or gas, don't over feed, discontinue before the puppy matures.